Implementing __eq__ for class hierarchy
This question is about how __eq__ should be implemented in a class hierarchy.
Let's say we have the following setup:
class Person:
    """A person with a name."""

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, type(self)):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.name == other.name

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Person("{self.name}")'


class Student(Person):
    """A student with a name and a student id."""

    def __init__(self, name, student_id):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.student_id = student_id

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Student("{self.name}", {self.student_id})'

The question is specifically about how should __eq__ be implemented?
The way it is written in the above code block results in:
p = Person("SomeName")
s = Student("SomeName", 1)
print(p == s)  # True

As s is an instance of a class derived from the class of instance p, the first call is
s.__eq__(p). # NotImplemented, as Person is not the same class or a subclass of Student

Since NotImplemented was returned, the following call is made:
p.__eq__(s)  # True, as Student is a subclass of Person and the name attribute of both instances are identical

But "should" an instance of a derived class ever considered to be equal (value equality) to an instance of a parent class?
If the answer to this question is "no", we can't rely on the __eq__ method (as it was written above) via inheritance, but must override it in the subclass.
Maybe this is contextual and case-to-case dependant, but if one would want to allow value equality to be True only when the types of both instances in the comparison are identical, couldn't we write __eq__ as:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if type(self) != type(other):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.name == other.name

As Person != Student the == operator would fall back to object identity which would return False.
What is the correct approach to the __eq__-paradigm in this situation?

I don't think there's a general answer to this, you need to decide what equality means in specific cases. E.g. should a dict and OrderedDict be equal if they have the same elements?

It's worth noting that the first call is s.__eq__(p) only because Person.__eq__ isn't defined. If it were defined, p.__eq__(s) would be called immediately. (That lets the parent class make a decision it is happy with, but easily overridden by subclasses.)

@chepner "only because Person.__eq__ isn't defined" - It is defined.

Sorry, I meant Student.__eq__.

@chepner sorry, why doesn't p.__eq__(s) get called first? i.e. Person.__eq__(p, s)?

@chepner ah, because of "If the operands are of different types, and the right operand’s type is a direct or indirect subclass of the left operand’s type, the reflected method of the right operand has priority, otherwise the left operand’s method has priority. " ?

@chepner That's defined, too. Inherited. And even if I redefine it (copying the code), s.__eq__(p) still gets tried first. You got the rule wrong.

Generally speaking, subclasses are supposed to substitutable with their base(s), which would include comparison. But of course this is not required or true in every circumstance and we know there are many examples where subclasses violate LSP in other ways. It's up to you to decide what is correct and prudent for your situation.

What do you want the comparison to do? Just compare the self.name attribute? Please state clearly what fields/attributes or any other way that indicates whether two objects are equal.

Why not use a more generalized type checker in your method to allow for all possible Person derivatives?
if not isinstance(other, Person): return NotImplemented

This way, a Student and a Person are always a Person instance.

I think they want to ensure that if instances of two different subclasses are compared, they'll never be equal.
